# How can I add a comma to separate each group of three digits with jinja?

Tags: django, jinja2

for this, which filter should i use?

Project Total weight = 1000000

{{project.total_weight}} >> 1.000.000

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Python's string formatting syntax:

```
{{ '{:,}'.format(project.total_weight)
```

Here's how I tested that in a playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    project:
      total_weight: 1000000
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '{:,}'.format(project.total_weight) }}"
```

The above will output:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "1,000,000"
}
```

This is documented in the [docs for the `format` method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec):

> The ',' option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator. For a locale aware separator, use the 'n' integer presentation type instead.